# Record elevation profile dot by Google Maps

Tags: html, css

How do I extract the data that appears in the div `elevation-profile-hover-dot` class in Google Maps?

This div changes the values ​​as the mouse passes over the elevation levels of the terrain. I would like to save them in Excel. 
The data are located [here](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/Laureate+International+Universities,+UniRitter+(Campus+FAPA),+Av.+Manoel+Elias,+2001+-+Passo+das+Pedras,+Porto+Alegre+-+RS,+91240-261/Pontif%C3%ADcia%E2%80%8B+Universidade+Cat%C3%B3lica+do+Rio+Grande+do+Sul+-+Av.+Ipiranga+-+Praia+de+Belas,+Porto+Alegre+-+RS,+90160-092/@-30.0445165,-51.1832971,13z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x9519763cac2bb605:0x43dd87263dead867!2m2!1d-51.1230839!2d-30.03231!1m5!1m1!1s0x9519781ac0c56319:0x79d4791483a97ec4!2m2!1d-51.1749011!2d-30.0573733!3e2%20here)

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried.

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onmousemove.asp